# Why doesn't Ubuntu on VMware recognize my wireless connection?

Tags: 11.04, wireless, vmware

I have installed Ubuntu 11.04 on [VMware](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VMware) on a Windows 7 host OS.

Wireless connection is working fine on the host OS but Ubuntu is not even recognizing it.

What can be the problem here? Why is Ubuntu not recognizing Wireless network? What can I do to be able to use Wireless network in the guest OS in vmware.

Comment: First thing is to check your additional drivers and enable .

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is that VMWare's "Automatic" default appears to be your LAN (wired) connection, instead of the wireless.

Change it explicitly from `Edit --> Virtual Network Editor` as shown below:

[image]

Comment: edit what?!
i saw wht u r tryin to tell in a youtube vid, bt after extracting the contents of vmware setup i didnt find any vmnetconfg.exe
Isnt tht wht u r refering to? How do i proceed?

Comment: Wht VMwr vrsn? Wrksttn/Plyr? Ths apprs **aftr** u hv instlld VMwr, nt bfr.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered the same problem. I also run Ubuntu 11.04 on VMware on a Windows 7 host OS. You need to get a usb dongle in order to connect to the internet because virtual machines can't expose the physical wireless cards. All of that is using a virtualization layer. So I recommend you to get a usb dongle.

Comment: **Bridged networking** is for more advanced networking needs such as network simulations and running servers in a guest operating system. When enabled, VMware connects to one of your installed network cards and exchanges network packets directly, circumventing your host operating system's network stack.